# Which one is correct: 'She was the first woman ever elected as President' or 'She was the first woman ever to be elected as President'?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage, esl

I think both sentences are ok but my teacher said I could only use the latter? I have also asked some friends yet they gave different opinions, so I'm not sure which one is proper. please help.

Comment: I think both are fine.  Ask her for the reasons she thinks the first one is wrong.

Comment: 'To-be deletion' is actually [covered on ELL!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77374/to-be-deletion) 'I knew that _consider_ allows 'to be deletion'. _Everybody considers him to be the best person for the job._ This sentence can be written in the following way: _Everybody considers him the best person for the job._' ... [@Nazmul Hassan] Admittedly, the sentence structure is not identical.

Comment: Unless the sentence is talking about Khertek Anchimaa-Toka, it does not really matter which variant is correct *grammatically*, because then neither is correct *factually*.

Comment: First ever is first., the “ever” that complicates the tense.

Answer (score 5):

The construction "ever to be elected as" (compared to "ever elected as") is used less frequently but both  are correct and used often enough ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ever+elected+as%2Cever+to+be+elected+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cever%20elected%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20to%20be%20elected%20as%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cever%20elected%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cever%20to%20be%20elected%20as%3B%2Cc0)).

It is interesting to notice that "elected president" is much more frequent than "elected **as** president" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elected+president%2Celected+as+president&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celected%20president%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celected%20as%20president%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Celected%20president%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celected%20as%20president%3B%2Cc0)).